# How to remove a live Pod from load balancing to debug?

Tags: kubernetes

Is it possible to take a pod out of rotation to debug some issue? or ability to create a pod from same replication controller without letting it serve live traffic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find the best solution is to take a Pod that was created by the controller and change the labels on it in a way that it is excluded from the Service(s). The controller will spawn another Pod to replace the now missing one.

```
kubectl label pod mypod app- myotherlabel- debug=true
```